# Why does posting Image with data using axios to django-rest-framework gives 404 error?

Tags: django, reactjs, image, django-rest-framework, http-status-code-404

I am using `django-rest-framework` and posting the data but it gives me **404 error** only if I add image to it. Without image, the data is posted and `modelviewset` works perfectly.

**Error screen:**

[image: Error]

My **urls.py**:

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserView, 'user')
router.register(r'teachers', TeacherView, 'teacher')
router.register(r'students', StudentView, 'student')
router.register(r'classes', ClassView, 'class')
router.register(r'subjects', SubjectView, 'subject')
router.register(r'institutes', InstituteView, 'institute')
router.register(r'enrolls', EnrolledView, 'enrolled')

router.register(r'quizes', QuizView, 'quizes')
router.register(r'questions', QuestionView, 'questions')
router.register(r'options', OptionView, 'options')
router.register(r'answers', AnswerView, 'answers')
router.register(r'attemptedQuestions',
                AttemptedQuestionView, 'attemmptedQuestion')
router.register(r'attemptedQuizes', AttemptedQuizesView, 'attemptedQuizes')

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

My views.py:

```
class QuizView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = QuizSerializer
    queryset = Quiz.objects.all()


class QuestionView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = QuestionSerializer
    queryset = Question.objects.all()


class OptionView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = OptionSerializer
    queryset = Option.objects.all()


class AnswerView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = AnswerSerializer
    queryset = Answer.objects.all()


class AttemptedQuizesView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = AttemptedQuizesSerializer
    queryset = attempted_quizes.objects.all()


class AttemptedQuestionView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = AttemptedQuestionSerializer
    queryset = attempted_question.objects.all()
```

**EDIT**

**Stack Trace**:
[Stack Trace after the error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMBo8.png)

**Quiz Model**:

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    Pin = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Live = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    asset = models.FileField(upload_to='Quiz_assets',
                             default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Description = models.TextField()
    Start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    End_time = models.DateTimeField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    Student = models.ManyToManyField(
        acModels.Student, through='attempted_quizes')
    Subject = models.ForeignKey(
        acModels.Subject, related_name="Quiz", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Also, everything works fine on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with you posting the images. Your URL has /1 at the end. It means Django will try to fetch the Quiz with ID = 1. As you are using PUT method, Django will try to update the quiz with ID = 1. When there is no such quiz with ID = 1, It throws a 404 error. Just remove /1 from the URL and post it again. In the case of PUT, append the ID that actually exists in DB. It will work.

Comment: Kindly read the question again, the data is updated if I put the request without image. It doesn't work *with* the image, for clarification the id exists in the db that's why it's getting updated without the image

Comment: can you put stack trace and your Quiz model definition?

Comment: Please check out the updated question above for the stack trace ( more of response from server because I am running it on debug mode to solve this error) and model of Quiz. Thanks in advance! Also, it's weird because everything works fine on my local PC.

Comment: @Kirti Hi, looking at the error, I still thinks it is an URL issue. Can you please try after removing the end slash. Just remove "/" from the end. If still does not work, can you upload a minimum code on GitHub. I can try to replicate the issue from there.

Comment: django requires the trailing slash. We can switch of this by explicitly defining  `trailing_slash=False` but I have clearly not done that. I have tried that after reading your comment but the problem still remains and I don't think you can locally produce this error as I said that it works fine in my local pc. I am facing this issue only in the server.